# Javascript click specific to ID

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div setup like so:

```
<div class="content">
    <button class="show-comments" id="content1"></button>
</div>

<div class="comments-wrapper" id="comment1"></div>

<div class="content">
    <button class="show-comments" id="content2"></button>
</div>

<div class="comments-wrapper" id="comment2"></div>
```

I have the following code:

```
$('.show-comments').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.comments-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

As you would assume, the code works but on a class basis. I'd like for it to open up only the .comments-wrapper of its associated id (i.e. open slideToggle comments2 if content 2 button is clicked and so on and so on).

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.show-comments').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".content").next('.comments-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Note that this is dependent on the `.content` element being immediately followed by the `.comments-wrapper`.

If you have access to modify the html itself, I would suggest adding a wrapper element and then doing the following to avoid the reliance on the exact order of elements:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <button class="show-comments" id="content1"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="comments-wrapper" id="comment1"></div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        <button class="show-comments" id="content2"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="comments-wrapper" id="comment2"></div>
</div>
```

```
$(this).closest(".wrapper").find('.comments-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
```

This way, if you add an element between the `.content` and the `.comments-wrapper` it does not break the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$(this).parent("div").next('.comments-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
```

This will find the related div of class `.comments-wrapper` and slide toggle.

And a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xCJQB/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.show-comments').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var num = this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0];
    $("#comment" + num).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/7pkyk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Use **this** context

```
   $(this).closest('.comments').next('.comments-wrapper').slideToggle('slow');
```

If it is not the immediate element then you might try this as well

```
$(this).closest('.comments')
       .nextAll('.comments-wrapper').first().slideToggle('slow');
```

Comment: This implies that `.contents-wrapper` is a descendant of `this` which it is not.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a common class to associate a button with a div.

html:

```
<div class="content">
    <button class="show-comments group1" id="content1"></button>
</div>

<div class="comments-wrapper group1" id="comment1">1</div>

<div class="content">
    <button class="show-comments group2" id="content2"></button>
</div>

<div class="comments-wrapper group2" id="comment2">2</div>
```

javascript:

```
$('.show-comments').click(function(e){
    var associate = $(this).attr('class').match(/group\d+/).pop();
    var selector = '.comments-wrapper.' + associate;
    e.preventDefault();
    $(selector).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMNfJ/